# HTTP 404 while sending message from SAP PI to other system

Tags: integration, httpresponse, sap-pi, sap-xi

The error from PI when I try to send to SAP system is:

> ```
> Transmitting the message to endpoint http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:50400/sap/xi/engine?type=entry
>   using connection jdbc_http://sap.com/xi/XI/System failed, due to:
> com.sap.engine.interfaces.messaging.api.exception.MessagingException:
>   Received HTTP response code 404: Not Found
> ```

When I am trying the link http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:50400/sap/xi/engine?type=entry I am getting the error HTTP 404.

Can someone tell me what to check?

Thanks

PS: where can I change the port?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the port in the above url (http : //xxx.xx.xx.xx:50400/sap/xi/engine?type=entry). It is 50000 instead of 50400.

The solution must be done in the following path: SAP XI transaction: SXMB_IFR. Then System Landscape Directory->Business Systems->INTEGRATION_SERVER_VPD->INTEGRATION TAB.

Here in the PIPELINE URL exists the wrong url and here you must correct it.

Thanks​